# bash awk with ps cannot print the results correctly

Tags: awk, sed

I want to get the related pids which match certain pattern, and then show the results with the pids and the matching part of the commands

samples results from ps (note that the target column is not necessary $9. eg $9 in line 1 and $10 in line 2):

```
root     23775     1  0 18:40 ?        00:00:01 /bin/bash /opt1/scripts/datamon/check_usage.sh -t 10

root     23777     1  0 18:40 ?        00:00:01 /bin/bash /opt1/servers/rt/extract_data.sh /opt1/scripts/datamon/results.data
```

what I am doing is:

```
pat1="/opt1/scripts/"

ps -ef | grep 'datamon' | awk -v RS='\n' -v pattern="$pat1" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i == /^pattern/) {print $2" "$i}}}'

the results obtained via the above commands are (pids are correct but not the command):

23775 0

23777 0
```

but actually what i want is:

```
23775 /opt1/scripts/datamon/check_usage.sh

23777 /opt1/scripts/datamon/print_results.sh
```

question:

1 why I got "0" instead of the matching commands?

2 how can I print the correct results above?

Comment: It feels like you are reinventing the wheel. Take a look at `man pgrep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second part you are doing a string compare `==` instead of using  `~` for a regex match.

If you print `/^pattern/` it will give 0.

So `if($i == /^pattern/)` becomes `if(0 == 0)` and is true for field 4, which has 0 in the data and is printed.

---

You can print field 9 instead of `$i` as that field contains the data that you are interested in.

```
pat1="/opt1/scripts/"

awk -v pattern="$pat1" '
{
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
  if($i ~ pattern) {
    print $2" "$9
  }
}
}' file
```

Output

```
23775 /opt1/scripts/datamon/check_usage.sh
23777 /opt1/servers/rt/extract_data.sh
```

You can also print the field where the match is with `print $2" "$i` but then the output will be:

```
23775 /opt1/scripts/datamon/check_usage.sh
23777 /opt1/scripts/datamon/results.data
```

Comment: oh my bad, you r right. i've tried to use ~ instead but it gave me nothing... thanks

Comment: @xxjoe Did you write it as `ps -ef | grep 'datamon' | awk -v pattern="$pat1" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ pattern) {print $2" "$9}}}'`

Comment: i cant remember correctly but perhaps with == i could use ^pattern, with ~ it doesnt work with variable, eg if ($i ~ ^pattern) returns Unexpected token, but if i type ($i ~ "^/opt1") it works. how to use ^(variable) with ~ may i ask?

Comment: ok i figured it out, i need to pass it in the pat1 as  pat1="^\/opt1"

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. We need NOT to traverse through all fields, since its output of `ps` command so values will be searched in 9th and 10th fields, please try following.

```
pat1="/opt1/scripts/"
awk -v pattern="$pat1" 'index($9,pattern) || index($10,pattern){print $2,$9}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ pat1="/opt1/scripts/"
$ ps -ef | sed -En "/datamon/{s~[^ ]* +([^ ]* +).*($pat1[^ ]*).*?~\1\2~p}"
23775     /opt1/scripts/datamon/check_usage.sh
23777     /opt1/scripts/datamon/results.data
```